# How can I prove algorithm correctness?

Tags: java, algorithm, correctness

I have a problem with this exercise in Java, I don't understand how to prove this sum method in Java

This is what I made :

```
P(0) : If r=0 and i=0 => r=0+a[0]

p(i+1) : r'= r + a[i] and i'=i+1
       r'=r + a[i] + a[i+1]
```

```
public static int sum(int[] a) {
    int r = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < a.length) {
        r = r + a[i];
        i = i + 1;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: According to your formula you should return `r + a[i] + a[i+1]`

Comment: @DWuest: test runs are never a proof.

Comment: As a hint, consider what the n of P(n) should be. I would suggest it be the length of the array -- in which case your P(0) assertion doesn't hold, since `a[0]` is undefined (it's an IndexOutOfBoundsException, in Java). Then for P(n+1), you need to make assertions about the loop as it acted in P(n) vs how it acts in P(n+1). What are the possible values of `i` in both of those loops? How do they map to each other?

Answer (score 1):

The loop invariant should express that `r` equals the sum of the elements of `a` from index `0` to index `i`, excluded. I.e. `r = Sum(k<i: a[k])`.

Then we can annotate

```
int r = 0;
int i = 0;
/* r = Sum(k<i: a[k]) */
while (i < a.length) {
    r = r + a[i];
    /* r = Sum(k<i: a[k]) + a[i] = Sum(k<i+1: a[k]) */
    i = i + 1;
    /* r = Sum(k<i: a[k]) */
}
/* r = Sum(k<=a.length: a[k]) */
```

The crux of the proof is

```
Sum(k<i: a[k]) + a[i] = Sum(k<i+1: a[k])
```

expressing that the sum is obtained incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to define a set of inputs along with their expected outputs.  If this is for an exercise, you may be given these values, or you may need to calculate a handful of them by hand.  Then I would write unit tests using those known inputs to see if each output matches the expected value.  If you find places where they don't match, double check both your algorithm *and* the expected values.  Work through the steps of each side-by-side and figure out which one is wrong (or if both are wrong).

Another option is to write the same algorithm in another language; ideally, one where you can't copy-paste the algorithm's implementation to prevent sharing common bugs.  Then run both with a *ton* of inputs.  If both implementations have matching results for every input, you can have a higher confidence that both are correct.

A third option is to find a set of invariants, i.e. things that are provably true at various stages of the algorithm.  Then write tests (or just throw in `assert` statements) at all of those points that show that the invariants hold.  Things like `for every iteration of the "i" loop, r' >= r`.  Then run it against a large range of inputs, and if any of those assertions fail, you can start digging in and figuring out what edge case you forgot to handle in your algorithm (e.g. What if the input is empty?  How do I handle negative numbers?  etc.)

Comment: Testing is NOT a proof means.

Comment: Running with *a ton of inputs* is a quite naive approach. For two reasons: usually, algorithms fail on the boundary cases rather than inside the domain. Tons of inputs are useless unless you focus on the boundaries; otherwise, the tons are virtually equivalent to a single case. Even so, the probability of finding a bug by arbitrary tests tends to be infinitesimal as soon as there are a handful of state variables.